# Applying the method of lines to a partial differential equation and using Runge-kutta method in a matlab code

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, runge-kutta-methods

By method of lines I converted the PDE

`u_t=u_{xx},` 
with the initial and boundary conditions

```
u(0,t)=u(0.1,t)
u(0,x)=sin(2*pi*x)
```

to a system of ODEs, as follows

```
function ut=pde1(t,u)
%
% Problem parameters
 % global ncall
  xl=0.0;
  xr=1.0;
  d=10;
  a=10;
%
% PDE
  n=length(u);
  h=((xr-xl)/(n-1));
  for i=1:n
    if(i==1)     ut(i)=0.0;
    elseif(i==n) ut(i)=0;
    else         ut(i)=d*(u(i+1)-2.0*u(i)+u(i-1))/h^2;
    end
  end
  ut=ut';
%
```

Now I am solving the ODEs `ut` by Runge-kutta method as follows:

```
%Initial condition
  n=500;
  for i=1:n
    u0(i)=sin((2*pi)*(i-1)/(n-1));
  end
  t0=0.0;
  tf=0.1;
  tout=linspace(t0,tf,n);
    y=zeros(n,length(tout));
 y(:,1)=u0';
    h=1/n;

    for i = 1 : length(tout)
        t=tout(i);
         k1 = pde_1(t,y(:,i));
         k2 = pde_1(t+h/2, y(:,i)+h*k1/2);
         k3 = pde_1(t+h/2, y(:,i)+h*k2/2);
         k4 = pde_1(t+h, y(:,i)+h*k3);
         y(:,i+1) = y(:,i) + h*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6;

    end

    y  
    plot(tout,y(:,1))
```

but the outputs are NAN! any help?

Comment: Why don't you use one of the Matlab built-in version of Runge-Kutta algorithm like ode45 ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I am avoiding the build functions at this level for some a reason, I am  considering some  different types of runge kutta

Comment: Please correct the boundary conditions, order of variables, 0.1 vs. 1.0, is this a periodic b.c. or are both boundaries zero? If periodic, then your implementation is wrong.

Comment: There are several problems with the code. As @LutzL pointed out, the problem statement is not consistent with the implementation. However, the reason behind your NaNs is that the CFL condition is not satisfied. For the diffusion equation you need the the time step $h$ to scale as $dx^2$ (where $dx$ is the spatial step), but in the code its simply set to $h = dx/10$.

Comment: @ekkilop you right, the stability condition should be satisfied